# Android: Display Image from SD CARD

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-imageview

This is driving me insane!  Here's my code (I know this file exists):

```
File imageFile = new File("/sdcard/gallery_photo_4.jpg");
ImageView jpgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
jpgView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

The error occurs on that last line (line 28, referenced below).

Error output:

```
W/dalvikvm(  865): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(  865): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  865): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.camera/org.example.camera.Imgview}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
E/AndroidRuntime(  865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime(  865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(  865):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime(  865):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  865):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  865):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  865):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  865):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(  865):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(  865):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  865): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  865):    at org.example.camera.Imgview.onCreate(Imgview.java:28)
E/AndroidRuntime(  865):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(  865):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  865):    ... 11 more
W/ActivityManager(   59):   Force finishing activity org.example.camera/.Imgview
```

My layout looks like (probably not necessary):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scaleType="center">
</ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Did u try to verify that file has been read after this line: File imageFile = new File("/sdcard/gallery_photo_4.jpg");
just try printing the file size?

Comment: imageFile.length() returns 4663

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would rather use a [`BitmapFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29) to decode the Image from the file-path:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
jpgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

The Docs say:

> If the specified file name is null, or cannot be decoded into a
>   bitmap, the function returns null.

Can you check if the code works with another image and if you can open your image on your PC thought. Maybe the file is corrupt.

Comment: setImageBitmap(), but yeah, I had tried that before, and it gives me the exact same error.  thanks.

Comment: thanks again.  I pushed a new image, and it gave me the same error.  I should be getting an android phone soon to test with, I'm curious whether it will work there.  This is so frustrating!

Comment: What Android version runs on your Emulator?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'm running on 2.2

Comment: @LukasKnuth how can we access the image which is store in hidden folder within the SdCard? Example (.demo/abc.png)

Comment: @ShubhamSejpal pass the path into the `decodeFile()`-function. It shouldn't matter if the folders are hidden, as long as you have read-permission on the folder.

Answer (score 10):

This code worked for me finally:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView jpgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/sample-1.jpg");
    jpgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Crash was happening because setContentView() was not performed before attaching the jpgview:

code that was crashing:

```
    ImageView jpgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/sample-1.jpg");
    jpgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + PATH_TO_IMAGE;
return Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath)
```

Comment: thanks.  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns "/mnt/sdcard" so that helps.  But it still gives me the same error at jpgView.setImageDrawable(drawable)

Answer (score 3):

USE THIS LINE OF CODE FOR GETTING IMAGE FROM SDCARD. AND THEN DISPLAY IT IN YOUR IMAGEVIEW

where "FileInputOutput" is a folder in your sdcard

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/FileInputOutput/img1.jpg"; 
            File imgFile = new File(path);
            if(imgFile.exists())
        {
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());                  
                ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }
            else                    
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"no IMAGE IS PRESENT'",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Please don't post the exact same answer to multiple questions.

Comment: ok i will! But i did it only, so that the user could find it easy, as a beginner i am learning too much here ...                            Thanks for advise

Comment: I think there is no problem to post same answer to multiple questions in case that the answer does match the questions exactly. I think you are very kind and correct to post your answer here. Thank you @Pir Fahim Shah. And I think you can ignore the suggestion of George Stocker.

Comment: @rml Thanks for appreciating me, yes i have the same idea, that as this forum is only about to get a solution of your problem so its not a jeopardy if i'll post the answer to many question if it match with the quality of the question then so.

Comment: @PirFahimShah FYI `pls don't shout at` **us**

Comment: @maveň LOL, yeah, actually in past i was been criticized for my precious work