# Android ImageAdapter setImageResource

Tags: android, imageview

Below are my codes. I'm trying to retrieve images from my sd card into a gridview. I am having problems with my codes. I cant figure out how to set images into my imageview. I got the error "The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (String)"in my ImageAdapter

```
public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {
    private String[] mFileStrings;
    private File[] listFile;
    GridView grid;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set title for the GridView
        setTitle("GridView");
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_view);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "Tutorial");

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listFile = file.listFiles();
            mFileStrings = new String[listFile.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                mFileStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
            }
        }

        grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, mFileStrings));
    }
```

ImageAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] data;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c, String[] d) {
        mContext = c;
        data=d;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // Create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(data[position]); //The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (String)
        return imageView;
    }


}
```

**MY EDITS**

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        File imgFile = new File("" + data[position]);
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        return imageView;

    }
```

LOGCAT :

```
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:389)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:418)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at com.androidbegin.gridview.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:46)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2201)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1026)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2265)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1624)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2628)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
04-12 14:18:59.811: E/AndroidRuntime(27379):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What does the documentation for ImageView say about the method?  setImageResource(int)

Comment: Sorry Simon, I'm not sure what you meant

Comment: *is my code, not *are my codes. Sorry, _biggest_ pet peeve of mine.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html  My point is, the best way for you to help yourself is to learn to use the documentation and the debugger.  We can give you a fish or teach you how to fish.  Your call.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725718/android-display-image-from-sd-card

Comment: check my edited ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15964227/1168654

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting imageView.setImageResource(data[position]) where data is array of strings.
You need to decode the file path as a bitmap and then set the same to your imageview.

In your `getView()`

```
File imgFile = new  File(""+data[position]);
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Edit:

Also you can use LazyList or Universal Image Loader to display images from your sdcard.
[What's LazyList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621936/whats-lazylist/15622374#15622374). Lazy List does scaling down to reduce memory consumption. Universal Image Loader works on the same principle of LazyList but it has much more Configuration Options.

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

```
  //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
  private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
     try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new   BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

If bitmaps are too large you need to scale them and then display the same in imageview. Also you should be using a **view holder for smooth scrolling and performance**. You should recycle bitmaps when not in use. visible views in gridview are not recycled. You can use LazyList or Universal Image Loader.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70. The talk is about viewholder and list view performance. The same holds good for gridview.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. Load bitmaps efficiently.

If you run into memory leaks use MAT Analyzer to find and fix the issue.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk.

Comment: Please check my edit. I'm trying to put images into my gridview and not imageview.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this in your adapter

```
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/photo.jpg");
ImageView mImgView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
mImgView1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

here you have to do `File f = new File(""+data[position]);`

**Edited:** You are getting `OutOfMemoryError` so, i ll saggest you..

### [**How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

check all answer of above link.

Answer (score 0):

for managing `Local file Path` and `Online url path` for your `BaseAdpter` `lazy Loading` is more helps full to [See](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

just need care in Your `BaseAdpter` about

```
ImageLoader imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context);
...
imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, imageView);
```