# Android : Clickable link of sdcard storage

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, clickable

I want to display links which have format such as`/sdcard/Pictures/` etc in textview as clickable link with highlight and underline. I often use `Linkify`for display links, however, this does not support storage links (only web, email etc).
Is there any possible way for that?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend displaying the image in an ImageView in an Activity.

You can put logic in your `onClick(View v)` to open the contents of the TextView in a new activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowImageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("imageLocation", v.getText());
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then in your ShowImageActivity's onCreate() :

```
    ImageView jpgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/sample-1.jpg");
    jpgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9509948/5486718

If you need to you can alternatively add a custom intent to the linkify:

```
String newActivityURL = "content://com.example.yourapp.yourtargetactivity/";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[/sdcard/]+[[a-f][0-9]]+[.jpg]");
Linkify.addLinks(hashView, pattern, newActivityURL);
```

Comment: Not really I need to display an image man. I know how to open files in sdcard and display it. However, that's not what I need. I need to make a link in textview clickable (Thats when you click it the browser will appear with the directory). Linkify can let me do that with URL, however, not sdcard directory. And that's the problem.