# BitmapFactory shows a blank screen in the app

Tags: java, android, ocr, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

Hello I have tried all the solutions on the Stack like checking for the overflow and changing the sample size multiple times. Is there any other way that I can get the picture on the app in Bitmap format.

```
protected void onPhotoTaken()
    {

        Log.i( "MakeMachine", "onPhotoTaken" );
        _taken = true;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        options.inSampleSize = 4;
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( _path,options);
        _image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        _field.setVisibility( View.GONE );

    }
```

Anyways any help would be appreciated. I would love to hear a workaround as well.

My layout.xml is :-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/field"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No Image"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take Photo"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have also tried the online project https://github.com/priyankvex/Easy-Ocr-Scanner-Android but it doesn't work for me. I hope somebody can help. The answer on this stackoverflow question also presents the exact same solution that I perormed [Android: Display Image from SD CARD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725718/android-display-image-from-sd-card) but it just doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you post your `layout.xml`?

Comment: I posted the layout.xml

Comment: `BitmapFactory shows a blank screen in the app`. BitmapFactory cannot show you anything. It only can handle bitmaps.

Comment: So I would like to save the image that has been saved on the sd card to put it on my app. Could you please suggest me how to do it. Also mostly it gives me an error while opening. Could you also tell me why it is not coming on the app ?

Comment: It seems that you do not react on my comment.

Comment: Okay so couple of things I just feel that _image.setImageBitmap(bitmap) can set the image to the bitmap.So shouldn't the app be showing the image when I go to the app ?

Comment: That still is no reaction on my comment.